# Exploiting PUT method in a server to upload a backdoor

Tags: http, file-upload

I was scanning an OSCP lab machine, and saw this
[image]

I tried to send a typical [put request](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_methods.htm) to test if I can put files on the server through netcat. 
[image]
However, I'm still getting a 404 error when accessing the uploaded file. 
[image]

Comment: It is called *potentially* for a reason - i.e. it does not need to be a problem but might. And, given your test it is probably not a problem in your case. For more see [How is HTTP PUT and DELETE methods insecure, if they really are?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/21413/how-to-exploit-http-methods.)

Comment: I guess you need to "try harder" :)

Comment: The correct c-len for that body is 58 with CRLF or 53 with LF. I don't have enough voodoo to resurrect Apache1.3 and check it rejected damaged/truncated request but I would expect it did.

Comment: Do not get rail-roaded by the output of Nikto, just because these are potentially allowed does not mean you can exploit them. I advise you enumerate more and do some threat modelling matching information you find to vulnerabilities and then to exploits…particularly those found on Exploit DB. As much as I hate to say it…Try harder. Another point I do not advise posting this on here as OffSec may not take to kindly to it, they have student forums for a reason. ;)