# Is the HTTP method OPTIONS secure nowadays?

Tags: http

I've read [How to exploit HTTP Methods](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/21413/how-to-exploit-http-methods):

> OPTIONS - this is a diagnostic method, which returns a message useful mainly for debugging and the like. This message basically reports, surprisingly, which HTTP Methods are active on the webserver. In reality, this is rarely used nowadays for legitimate purposes, but it does grant a potential attacker a little bit of help: it can be considered a shortcut to find another hole.
>
> Now, this by itself is not really a vulnerability; but since there is no real use for it, it just affects your attack surface, and ideally should be disabled.
>
> NOTE: Despite the above, OPTIONS method IS used for several legitimate purposes nowadays, for example some REST APIs require an OPTIONS request, CORS requires pre-flight requests, and so on. So there definitely are scenarios wherein OPTIONS should be enabled, but the default should still be "disabled unless required".

This post is a bit old now. What's up today with the OPTIONS methods? Most of the scans show that it's a vulnerability. Is it really dangerous?

I have no choice to use OPTIONS for some of my apps. What can I do to secure it?

Comment: I'd argue that any tool that claims that responding normally to HTTP `OPTIONS` is a vulnerability is simply broken. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS clearly says that `OPTIONS` is both Idempotent and Safe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say implementing the `OPTIONS` method, *in itself*, is not a significant security risk. Yes, it nicely enumerates which other methods are implemented by a server, but it is in the handling of *those other methods* that the potential for danger lies, not in the reporting that they *are* handled.

For example, the `TRACE` method can be a vector of attack. If you implement `OPTIONS`, and it includes `TRACE` in its response, a potential attacker can use `OPTIONS` to discover that `TRACE` is supported then decide to try and launch an attack on `TRACE`. However, if `OPTIONS` is not implemented, or it lies and says `TRACE` is not implemented, the attacker could *still* decide to try and mount an attack using `TRACE`. In fact, they are probably just as likely to not use the `OPTIONS` command at all and simply see if an attack on `TRACE` will work.

*You should focus on making sure that potentially unsafe methods (such as `TRACE`) are disabled or suitably protected, ahead of worrying whether `OPTIONS` tells an attacker they exist.*

---

The OSWAP
GitHub page on [Test HTTP Methods](https://github.com/OWASP/wstg/blob/master/document/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/02-Configuration_and_Deployment_Management_Testing/06-Test_HTTP_Methods.md) starts by listing the eight HTTP methods defined by RFC 2616 (HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS and CONNECT) but only mentions four that should be disabled (or sufficiently protected):

> More specifically, the methods that should be disabled are the following:
>
> - PUT: This method allows a client to upload new files on the web server. An attacker can exploit it by uploading malicious files (e.g.: an asp file that executes commands by invoking cmd.exe), or by simply using the victim's server as a file repository.
> - DELETE: This method allows a client to delete a file on the web server. An attacker can exploit it as a very simple and direct way to deface a web site or to mount a DoS attack.
> - CONNECT: This method could allow a client to use the web server as a proxy.
> - TRACE: This method simply echoes back to the client whatever string has been sent to the server, and is used mainly for debugging purposes. This method, originally assumed harmless, can be used to mount an attack known as Cross Site Tracing, which has been discovered by Jeremiah Grossman (see links at the bottom of the page).
>
> If an application needs one or more of these methods, such as REST Web Services (which may require PUT or DELETE), it is important to check that their usage is properly limited to trusted users and safe conditions.

And while it highlights how the `OPTIONS` command can be used by a tester to determine potential vulnerabilities:

> ### How to Test
>
> #### Discover the Supported Methods
>
> To perform this test, the tester needs some way to figure out which HTTP methods are supported by the web server that is being examined. The OPTIONS HTTP method provides the tester with the most direct and effective way to do that. RFC 2616 states that, “The OPTIONS method represents a request for information about the communication options available on the request/response chain identified by the Request-URI”.

Execution of a test-script only highlights the `TRACE` method as risky:

> The same test can also be executed using nmap and the http-methods NSE script:
>
> ```
> C:\Tools\nmap-6.40>nmap -p 443 --script http-methods localhost
>
> Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-11-04 11:52 Romance Standard Time
>
> Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
> Host is up (0.0094s latency).
> PORT    STATE SERVICE
> 443/tcp open  https
> | http-methods: OPTIONS TRACE GET HEAD POST
> | Potentially risky methods: TRACE
> |_See http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-methods.html
>
> Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 20.48 seconds
> ```

The rest of the OSWAP page discusses potential security problems (e.g. the potential of using `TRACE` to exfiltrate cookies tagged `httpOnly` into JavaScript), but *does not* talk of `OPTIONS` being a security concern.

Comment: Very much this, even if options is disabled an attacker can just try all known verbs. So unless you're using secret verbs it's an insignificant issue.